# QtCreator CMake editor indenting

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, indentation

I have my Qt Creator 3.1.1 setup to indent with 4 spaces on `Tab`, but for some reason tab key doesn't work when I edit `CMakeLists.txt`. This only happens when I open it with `CMake Editor`, it works when I use `Plain Text Editor`. Is this a bug or I need to configure it somehow to make `Tab` key work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.
This issue occured because I have enabled auto-indent. The value in the "Preferences->Text Editor->Behavior" tab "Typing->Tab key performs auto-indent" was set to something else to "Never".

So to fix this issue you you need to set "Tab key performs auto-indent" to "Never".

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer above, inside 'Options' window and 'Behavior' pane, have a look at 'Tab Policy' section as well as 'Cleanups upon Saving' - and check if it is really what you expect.

For me the settings there were not what I have expected and it was triggering issues, eg. in a Makefile, first command of a task looks like *line continuation* for Qt Creator so, upon saving, it was *"cleaning"* (= breaking) the indentation by replacing it with 4 spaces, that was incoherent with overall indentation in the script. Et voilà - error, make didn't work correctly!

As always, it is a very nice tool but one needs to know how to use it...